# What is meaning of the Maruti-stotra composed by Ramdas swami?

Tags: hanuman, language, stotra

I have recited this stotra since I was a child and although I have understood the meaning of some parts of it, I would love to get the meaning of the entire prayer.

Here is the [full text](http://www.voidcan.org/maruti-stotra/) for reference.

The language it is written in is Marathi, but anyone with knowledge of any Sanskrit based language may be able to interpret it.

Comment: This looks like Marathi, correct? It would be useful to update the question with the language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm really surprised there is no English translation to this famous stotra on Hanuman. I searched on the internet but wasn't able to find any, most of the "English" translations were just transliterated Sanskrit texts.

So I decided to translate it on my own since my native language happens to be Marathi.

A site where they hosted Samartha Ramadasa's books gave me a [PDF](http://www.samarthramdas400.in/literature/bhimrupi.pdf) of the stotra with a Marathi explanation that made my job easier. Sanskrit text is taken from [this site](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_otherlang_maraathii/bhiima.html).

> भीमरूपी महारुद्रा वज्र हनुमान मारुती ।
>
> वनारि अंजनीसूता रामदूता प्रभंजना ॥ १॥
>
> bhīmarūpī mahārudrā vajra hanumāna mārutī |
>
> vanāri aṃjanīsūtā rāmadūtā prabhaṃjanā || 1 ||
>
> **The large bodied, the wrathful one, diamond bodied Hanuman, the son of
> Maruta, who lives in the forest.**
>
> **The son of Anjana, the messenger of Rama, who is like a hurricane.**
>
> महाबळी प्राणदाता सकळां उठवी बळें ।
>
> सौख्यकारी  दुःखहारी धूर्त वैष्णव गायका ॥ २॥
>
> mahābal̤ī prāṇadātā sakal̤āṃ uṭhavī bal̤eṃ |
>
> saukhyakārī  duḥkhahārī dhūrta vaiṣṇava gāyakā || 2 ||
>
> **The all powerful, giver of life breaths, the one that rouses others by
> his strength.**
>
> **The bestow-er of happiness, the remover of sorrows, the  shrewd one,
> who is the singer of Vishnu's praises. (Alt: The one who is a devotee
> of Vishnu and a singer)**
>
> दीनानाथा हरीरूपा सुंदरा जगदांतरा ।
>
> पातालदेवताहंता भव्यसिंदूरलेपना ॥ ३॥
>
> dīnānāthā harīrūpā suṃdarā jagadāṃtarā |
>
> pātāladevatāhaṃtā bhavyasiṃdūralepanā || 3 ||
>
> **The empower-er of the feeble, the one with an ape's face, who is
> beautiful like the moon, the one that can go to the ends of the world.**
>
> **The destroyer of the lords of Patala, whose gigantic body is smeared
> with Sindura.**
>
> लोकनाथा जगन्नाथा प्राणनाथा पुरातना ।
>
> पुण्यवंता पुण्यशीला पावना परितोषका ॥ ४॥
>
> lokanāthā jagannāthā prāṇanāthā purātanā |
>
> puṇyavaṃtā puṇyaśīlā pāvanā paritoṣakā || 4 ||
>
> **The one who is the lord of the Lokas, who is the lord of the world,
> who is the lord of the life breaths, who is ancient.**
>
> **The one who is pure in mind, speech and body, who has pure character,
> son of Pavana: the pure one, The one who fulfills the desires of
> his devotees and bestows contentment.**
>
> ध्वजांगें उचली बाहो आवेशें लोटला पुढें ।
>
> काळाग्नि काळरुद्राग्नि देखतां कांपती भयें ॥ ५॥
>
> dhvajāṃgeṃ ucalī bāho āveśeṃ loṭalā puḍheṃ |
>
> kāl̤āgni kāl̤arudrāgni dekhatāṃ kāṃpatī bhayeṃ || 5 ||
>
> **With his arms raised like a flag staff he charges forward furiously.**
>
> **Even the fires of Yama, and Kaala tremble on seeing him in such a form.**
>
> ब्रह्मांडें माइलीं नेणों आंवळे दंतपंगती ।
>
> नेत्राग्नि चालिल्या ज्वाळा भ्रकुटी तठिल्या बळें ॥ ६॥
>
> brahmāṃḍeṃ māilīṃ neṇoṃ āṃval̤e daṃtapaṃgatī |
>
> netrāgni cālilyā jvāl̤ā bhrakuṭī taṭhilyā bal̤eṃ || 6 ||
>
> **The one in whose mouth the universe is composed when he bares(gnashes) his teeth.**
>
> **Whose eyes emit fire as he contracts his brows in forceful rage.**
>
> पुच्छ तें मुरडिलें माथां किरीटी कुंडलें बरीं ।
>
> सुवर्णकटिकांसोटी घंटा किंकिणि नागरा ॥ ७॥
>
> puccha teṃ muraḍileṃ māthāṃ kirīṭī kuṃḍaleṃ barīṃ |
>
> suvarṇakaṭikāṃsoṭī ghaṃṭā kiṃkiṇi nāgarā || 7 ||
>
> **The one with his tail coiled on his head as he sports a crown with
> splendid earrings.**
>
> **The tinkling bells on his golden girdle echo(everywhere).**
>
> ठकारे पर्वताइसा नेटका सडपातळू ।
>
> चपळांग पाहतां मोठें महाविद्युल्लतेपरी ॥ ८॥
>
> ṭhakāre parvatāisā neṭakā saḍapātal̤ū |
>
> capal̤āṃga pāhatāṃ moṭheṃ mahāvidyullateparī  || 8 ||
>
> **Stationed like a gigantic mountain, of perfect limbs and slender form.**
>
> **He is supple and moves in the blink of an eye like a great streak
> of lightning.**
>
> कोटिच्या कोटि उड्डणें झेपावे उत्तरेकडे ।
>
> मंदाद्रीसारिखा द्रोणू क्रोधें उत्पाटिला बळें ॥ ९॥
>
> koṭicyā koṭi uḍḍaṇeṃ jhepāve uttarekaḍe |
>
> maṃdādrīsārikhā droṇū krodheṃ utpāṭilā bal̤eṃ || 9 ||
>
> **The one that flew crores of distance towards the North and violently
> uprooted the Dronagiri that was like Mandrachal with his strength.**
>
> आणिला मागुती नेला आला गेला मनोगती ।
>
> मनासी टाकिलें मागें गतीसी तूळणा नसे ॥ १०॥
>
> āṇilā māgutī nelā ālā gelā manogatī |
>
> manāsī ṭākileṃ māgeṃ gatīsī tūl̤aṇā nase || 10 ||
>
> **Bringing the mountain (to Lanka) he returned and replaced it at the
> speed of the mind.**
>
> **Even the mind was overcome by his pace and none can match his
> velocity.**
>
> अणूपासोनि ब्रह्मांडायेवढा होत जातसे ।
>
> तयासी तुळणा कोठें मेरुमांदार धाकुटें ॥ ११॥
>
> aṇūpāsoni brahmāṃḍāyevaḍhā hota jātase |
>
> tayāsī tul̤aṇā koṭheṃ merumāṃdāra dhākuṭeṃ || 11 ||
>
> **From the size of the atom to the size of the universe, he expands.**
>
> **Where can one equate to his size the Meru and Mandara mountains?**
>
> ब्रह्मांडाभोंवते वेढे वज्रपुच्छें करूं शके ।
>
> तयासी तुळणा कैंची ब्रह्मांडीं पाहतां नसे ॥ १२॥
>
> brahmāṃḍābhoṃvate veḍhe vajrapuccheṃ karūṃ śake |
>
> tayāsī tul̤aṇā kaiṃcī brahmāṃḍīṃ pāhatāṃ nase || 12 ||
>
> **He can siege (circle) the universe with his diamond like tail.**
>
> **A comparison to him the universe has never seen.**
>
> आरक्त देखिलें डोळां ग्रासिलें सूर्यमंडळा ।
>
> वाढतां वाढतां वाढे भेदिलें शून्यमंडळा ॥ १३॥
>
> ārakta dekhileṃ ḍol̤āṃ grāsileṃ sūryamaṃḍal̤ā |
>
> vāḍhatāṃ vāḍhatāṃ vāḍhe bhedileṃ śūnyamaṃḍal̤ā || 13 ||
>
> **Whose eyes glimpsed the reddened sun and he went to swallow it. (For
> that) He grew to such and extent that he pierced the sunyamandala (the solar system).**
>
> धनधान्य पशुवृद्धि पुत्रपौत्र समग्रही ।
>
> पावती रूपविद्यादि स्तोत्रपाठें करूनियां ॥ १४॥
>
> dhanadhānya paśuvṛddhi putrapautra samagrahī |
>
> pāvatī rūpavidyādi stotrapāṭheṃ karūniyāṃ || 14 ||
>
> **Wealth, foodgrains, cattle, progeny flourish and one obtains health
> and knowledge when one recites/masters this stotra.**
>
> भूतप्रेतसमंधादि रोगव्याधि समस्तही ।
>
> नासती तूटती चिंता आनंदे भीमदर्शनें ॥ १५॥
>
> bhūtapretasamaṃdhādi rogavyādhi samastahī |
>
> nāsatī tūṭatī ciṃtā ānaṃde bhīmadarśaneṃ || 15 ||
>
> **Ghosts, zombies, spirits etc diseases and afflictions all worries are
> destroyed by the darshana of Hanuman and the devotee attains bliss.**
>
> हे धरा पंधराश्लोकी लाभली शोभली भली ।
>
> दृढदेहो निःसंदेहो संख्या चंद्रकलागुणें ॥ १६॥
>
> he dharā paṃdharāślokī lābhalī śobhalī bhalī |
>
> dṛḍhadeho niḥsaṃdeho saṃkhyā caṃdrakalāguṇeṃ || 16 ||
>
> **These 15 slokas, that provide gainfulness that purify the body and
> bestow serenity to the mind, are like the 15 digits of the moon in
> nature. (Moon is often said to have the quality of Amrita so these
> verses are like nectar)**
>
> रामदासीं अग्रगण्यू कपिकुळासि मंडणू ।
>
> रामरूपी अन्तरात्मा दर्शने दोष नासती ॥ १७॥
>
> rāmadāsīṃ agragaṇyū kapikul̤āsi maṃḍaṇū |
>
> rāmarūpī antarātmā darśane doṣa nāsatī || 17 ||
>
> **You are foremost among the devotees of Rama, the bringer of fame to
> the race of the Vanaras(Kapi).**
>
> **With the darshana of you, who has the form of Rama in his heart/soul,
> all faults vanish.**
>
> ॥ इति श्री रामदासकृतं संकटनिरसनं नाम श्री मारुतिस्तोत्रम् सम्पूर्णम् ॥
>
> || iti śrī rāmadāsakṛtaṃ saṃkaṭanirasanaṃ nāma
> śrī mārutistotram sampūrṇam ||
>
> **Hereby ends the Maruti Stotra which is capable of destroying all
> difficulties, composed by Samartha Ramadas**
>
> .....